# Why is there no constant introduced when computing the arc length?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, arc-length

I've recently started learning multivariable calculus. When reading about how to compute the length of a curve there is this formula:

$\int_{a}^{b} |\vec{r'}(t)| \,dt $

From my past understanding of integration, one should always introduce a arbitrary constant $C$, since the derivative of such a function that arbitrary constant is lost. Why is this not the case when integrating over the length of a curve?

An example from the litterature I'm reading:

"Find the length of the curve $\vec{r} = t^2\vec{i}+t^2\vec{j}+t^3\vec{k}$ from $t=0$ to $t=1$.

As a first step i'll take the derivative of $\vec{r}$.

$\vec{v}=\vec{r'}=2t\vec{i}+2t\vec{j}+3t^2\vec{k}$

Next I'll use the formula of finding the arc length.

$\int_{0}^{1} |\vec{r'}(t)| \,dt = $
$ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{8t^2+9t^4} \,dt = $
$ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{t^2(8+9t^2)} \,dt = $
$\int_{0}^{1} t\sqrt{8+9t^2} \,dt =\frac{1}{18}\frac{2}{3}*(8+9t^2)^{3/2}\bigg\rvert_{0}^{1}=1.7579$ (about this, more decimals of course).

This is correct with the answer in the book, but why do I not introduce an arbitrary constant when integrating? Is it simply because if we'd introduce such a constant, we'd not be able to figure out it's lenght? Given that we'd then have too many variables? Perhaps I have missed some key insight, or my mind is playing tricks..!

Comment: You are calculating *definite* integrals, not *indefinite* integrals, so there is no need for constants. Nevertheless try if you include a constant and see what happens.

Comment: Well that answers it.. Thank you! So given that the problem is bounded and as such calculable we don't introduce a constant. But if we'd wanted to give the general antiderivative of an arc length without any interval, then we'd need to introduce an arbitrary constant?

Trying to learn this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a Riemann integrable function an $F$ an antiderivative of $f$. If $c$ is a constant, then $G:=F+c$ is also an antiderivative of $f$.

We get

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx= G(b)-G(a)= F(b)+c-(F(a)+c)=F(b)-F(a).$$

Do you see what happens wit the contant $c$ ?

Comment: Yes I do! Thank you for your explanation.